# Ubuntu 14.04LTS 32bits VMWare Player 6 instal but don't work

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-player

I installed recently Ubuntu on my Laptop. Everything is working, But my motivation is to use Windows XP under VMware Player. I followed every tutorial I have found and many versions (started with last version 6.0.6).

The last version I downloaded is: VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.i386.bundle

I'm stuck  in this message (always):

```
Unable to start services.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-10958.log for details.
```

I don't know what I can do to solve this. Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: ...and what does the log say??? You need to post that info to get answers.